# Google Books Oauth access token authorization error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-oauth, google-books

Hi i have been developing an app that would let the user search for the books using the Google Books API. Everything was working fine until i wanted to access user's favorite books, add and delete them. The error is about authorization. The google books api says here to access the favorite books as

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves?key=yourAPIKey
>   Authorization: /* auth token here */

What i am doing is this.

```
var userId: String?
    if(UserStats.currentUser?.authentication.idToken != nil){
        userId = UserStats.currentUser?.authentication.idToken
    }
    guard let id = userId else{
        print("User Not authenticated")
        return
    }
    print("USer ID : \(id)")
    let theUrl = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves?key=AIzaSyBIDJ50ak-caS3M-6nSVbxdN_SmssAlTRI)")
    if let url = theUrl{
        print("Search Called")
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.setValue(id, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        print("URL : " + url.absoluteString)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            if response != nil{
                if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                    if(res.statusCode == 408)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(message: "Error : Request TimeOut", title: "Error", view: self)
                    }

                }
            }

            if error != nil{
                print("Error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                MessageBox.Show(message: (error?.localizedDescription)!, title: "An error occurred", view: self)

            }
            else{
                do{

                    let jsonData  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(jsonData)
                }catch{
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time i run the code it gives me error. The error is here

```
{
error =     {
    code = 401;
    errors =         (
                    {
            domain = global;
            location = Authorization;
            locationType = header;
            message = "Invalid Credentials";
            reason = authError;
        }
    );
    message = "Invalid Credentials";
};
}
```

I am using Google Sign in sdk for iOS and here is how i am trying to authenticate and it successfully done.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "1049478111900-4q2m623kj5m0fev7fbqq93tk7rgjvs2f.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

The sign in is successfull as i do see a Success printed when signed in successfully and also i am able to retrieve accessToken and idToken of the signed in user.
here is the idToken i got printed.

**ID Token for Signed In user**

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNiMDE1MDIxOWM5Y2NlZTBjY2Y3MDg2OTA4NmIxYjVmNGIzMGVmNWIifQ.eyJhenAiOiIxMDQ5NDc4MTExOTAwLTRxMm02MjNrajVtMGZldjdmYnFxOTN0azdyZ2p2czJmLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiMTA0OTQ3ODExMTkwMC00cTJtNjIza2o1bTBmZXY3ZmJxcTkzdGs3cmdqdnMyZi5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwOTI5NDQ5ODE2OTA4NjY1OTU5NyIsImVtYWlsIjoic2FsbWFubWFqaWQxNEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IlNMRzRoTGlrQXExZmQ2MnlnWklKR2ciLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0OTMxMTE4NjAsImV4cCI6MTQ5MzExNTQ2MH0.Ct1aGjA6K8Vev_FmdjCj5hGJKyALY9jUcakbp4HSesarK8LHjEe2wZ1-8FR-FEyufIDTPENEkYpSXQRGYuHKXYmykNq6LMcRSWmR2JV8P5hDxwYPKcMwG4EgcvrEHncVBzjinn652mVHap6uBzwC4nvbpprpGKuglxZrqBKSobBthZnDitgyuMseWUq0lrfunNyA89g3KD9twjMMIDTMnP40u6if10T7P6JyedSoDgoOZ6rmhQOckovA1ery1rPl0zwvoRrbZ2GS_z-Zzz8ujhfyuxex-0yYExhVF09Gl4lvf5zySnSSbIGi6MIYaZC3W0-WaU4t0Hgho1kujl3ryw

Please do help me with this issue. I have been working this all night and couldn't sort this out. Please let me know if there is any better approach or i can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves?access_token=YourToken)")
```

*Note: Key is used for public access access token is for private you only need one or the other*

Note 2: you can test this by placing

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves?access_token=YourToken
```

in any web browser.

**Option 2:**

Header should look like this

> Authorization, Bearer accessToken

I think you are missing bearer.

You do not need to do both of these one or the other is fine.

> When sending the access token in the "Authorization" request header
>      field defined by HTTP/1.1 [RFC2617], the client uses the "Bearer"
>      authentication scheme to transmit the access token.
>
> Authorization : Bearer AccessToken

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo I really appreciate the help. Can you tell me what do you mean by missing Bearer. Do you mean I should get access token and add a prefix as Bearer.append(access_token). Is that it?

Comment: Request.set value(bearer+access_token, "Authorization"). Is that what you are saying?

Comment: The actual header is Authorization  the value of the header should be "Bearer accessToken"   Really though try option one you shouldn't need to add the header it doesn't really matter which one you use.

Comment: I am not an ios dev I cant tell you how to do it sorry https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re  This is my .net code  AddHTTPRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

Comment: Okay, thanks I will try that and let you know. Hope that works.

Comment: Just put https ://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves?access_token=YourToken in a web browser its a http get it works.   Make sure you are sending the access token and not a refresh token or a key

Comment: Yes, that works but why does it not work in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142607/discussion-between-daimto-and-salman-ali).

Comment: I solved the problem. That was only my mistake. You were right the whole time. I had a very stupid misspelled something. I accidently made one ViewController the parent of the other so the search was called before authentication. Thanks a lot for the help.